# Merge Python 3 DataFrame rows that share a cell value, putting another value into a comma separated array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a Python DataFrame where emails are duplicated.  I'd like to find all the duplicates and merge them so that there are an array of account numbers attached to the email. I'd also like to preserve the 3rd column in the merged column.

```
AccountID Email                    Quality_3

1         blue@somedomain.com      High
2         red@somedomain.com
3         blue@somedomain.com      
4         green@somedomain.com     Medium
5         blue@somedomain.com
6         red@somedomain.com         
7         blue@somedomain.com
8         green@somedomain.com



AccountID         Email                  Quality_3
1, 3, 5, 7        blue@somedomain.com    High
2, 6              red@somedomain.com
4, 8              green@somedomain.com   Medium
```

I am looking at left and right joins, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_new=(df.astype(str).groupby('Email')['AccountID','Quality_3']
    .agg({'AccountID':lambda x: ','.join(x),'Quality_3':'first'}).reset_index())
print(df_new)

                  Email AccountID Quality_3
0   blue@somedomain.com   1,3,5,7      High
1  green@somedomain.com       4,8    Medium
2    red@somedomain.com       2,6      None
```